# How can I find real client ip address?

Tags: python, ip-address

How can I find IP address of clients in python?

Comment: What is the client connecting to? web server? FTP server? SSH server? ...?

Answer (score 7):

In general, you can't. If someone has a different computer make a request on behalf of their computer, then you only get network information about the machine you receive the connection from.

An HTTP proxy might add a X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: I used X-Forwarded, but it`s not worked.

Comment: Hence "might". The important bit of the answer was the first sentence.